# Delete struct node using pointer-to-pointer

Tags: c

Suppose that I have a linked list, the next function deletes struct node from the linked list

```
struct list **lpp;
for (lpp = &list; *lpp != NULL; lpp = &(*lpp)->next)
{
    if ((*lpp)->item == i)
    {
        *lpp = (*lpp)->next;
        break;
    }
}
```

please need explain about:

> 1. lpp = &(*lpp)->next, can I write it as lpp = lpp->next, is this not the same?
> 2. *lpp = (*lpp)->next

the bottom line , I do not see how this function deletes a struct node from the list

Comment: You haven't shown a function, you've shown a context-less snippet.

Comment: It doesn't. Perhaps you should show the function.

Comment: can you please show to me how do I delete a linked list node using double poniters?

Answer (score 2):

`lpp` points either to the first element of the list or to the `next` pointer of some element.

By `*lpp = (*lpp)->next` you are writing it directly into the memory.  E.g. consider a list

```
| el0 | -> | el1 | -> | el2 | -> NULL
 list     list->next
```

`list` from you code points to `el0` and `lpp = &list`.

Now, there are two cases:

- `el0` matches `i`: --> `list` becomes `|el0|.next` which is `el1`.  After running this function, you have

  `| el1 | -> | el2 | -> NULL
  list     list->next`
- `elX` matches `i` (with `X>0`): `lpp` is `&el_{X-1}.next` and by `*lpp = ...`, this `.next` will point to `elX.next`.  E.g. assuming `el1` matches, you get

  `| el0 | -> | el2 | -> NULL`

`lpp = &(*lpp)->next` is used to get a reference to `next`. A simple `lpp = lpp->next` does not suffice, because it are different types.  When you work on `lpp->next`, a `*lpp` is like `*lpp->next` which would dereference the content of the next element.

## Single list operations

Although unrelated to this question but due to other discussions, some more code...

Assuming a data structue  like

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

In real code, `data` would not be a member of this node but `struct node` would be a mix-in within another object and something like `container_of` is used to access it.  But for this question, keep it as above...

We can define some functions like

```
void slist_add(struct node *node, struct node *root)
{
    node->next = root->next;
    root->next = node;
}

void slist_remove(struct node **node)
{
    if (node)
        *node = (*node)->next;
}

struct node **slist_search(struct node *root, int key)
{
    struct node **ptr;

    for (ptr = &root->next; *ptr; ptr = &(*ptr)->next) {
        if ((*ptr)->data  == key)
            return ptr;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Then, we use an empty `struct node` as an anchor:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct node head = { .next = NULL };

    /* add a node */
    {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
        n->data = 23;

        slist_add(n, &head);
    }

    /* add a node */
    {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
        n->data = 42;

        slist_add(n, &head);
    }

    /* verify our expectations... */
    assert(head.next != NULL);
    assert(head.next->data == 42);

    assert(head.next->next != NULL);
    assert(head.next->next->data == 23);
    assert(head.next->next->next == NULL);

    /* remove the node */
    {
        struct node **ptr = slist_search(&head, 42);

        assert(ptr != NULL);
        assert(*ptr != NULL);
        assert((*ptr)->data == 42);

        if (ptr) {
           struct node *n = *ptr;
           slist_remove(ptr);
           free(n);
        }
    }

    /* remove the node */
    {
        struct node **ptr = slist_search(&head, 23);

        assert(ptr != NULL);
        assert(*ptr != NULL);
        assert((*ptr)->data == 23);

        if (ptr) {
           struct node *n = *ptr;
           slist_remove(ptr);
           free(n);
        }
    }

    assert(head.next == NULL);
}
```

Comment: It crashes!  Test like this. Add another node with `n1->data = 24;`  and remove just this node with `slist_search(&head, 24);` You do not handle `head` properly.

Comment: Still not fixed. Head is not handled properly. Hint: `void slist_add(struct node *node, struct node *root)` cannot work properly - use pointer to pointer.

Comment: @sg7 you removed/adjusted the `assert()` after adding other elements, right?

Comment: I just added a new node. I left all assertion as they were. I am getting `Assertion  'head.next->next == NULL' failed.`

Comment: @sg7 the assertions were used to document the layout of the list when executing *this* order of operations.  When other elements are added to the list, the layout changes and the assertions trigger.  The `main()` function is some kind of unit test and documentation; when tests are changed, the expected results must be adapted too ;)

Comment: As far I can see the program works only for one element. The `void slist_add(struct node *node, struct node *root)` does not move the `head` Adding more than one element to the list and removing it will crash the program.  Could you add  2 nodes to the list and remove the last added node?

Comment: @I have 2 element added to the list.  `slist_search(struct node *root, int key)` is able to find only one of them.

Comment: @sg7 `head` will never be moved (it is a static anchor); program has been extended to add/remove another element.  There are new `assert()` tests which verify `slist_search()` and I can not reproduce "is able to find only one of them".

Comment: I assume that it is a perfectly legal operation to clean the node by `free(n); *ptr = NULL;`  If I do so the second element will not be found. Looks like list connection is broken.

Comment: @sg7 no; I made a similar mistake in the very first variant of the program. `*ptr` must/should not be touched after `slist_remove()`; neither  by `*ptr = NULL` nor by `free(*ptr)`.  `*ptr` is `head.next` at this point (this is scope of the original question).

Comment: OK! Then I see NO problems! Thank you @ensc for the demo program and good discussion! I have Up Voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is an extremely simplified and incomplete node delete attempt.
You have to take care of the edge cases as well as actually `free` the memory.

This line:

> ```
>  *lpp = (*lpp)->next;
> ```

is responsible for `taking out` the node from the list. 
 It only works if `*lpp` is the list head and there is another element on the list.
 The `*lpp` points to the node which you do not need anymore and it is replaced by the the next node on the list

```
 (*lpp)->next;
```

> `lpp = &(*lpp)->next`, can I write it as `lpp = lpp->next`, is this not
>   the same?

No it is not. And `lpp = lpp->next` will not compile.

`&` is a dereference operator. It is obtaining the address of the node pointer.
You can write this line as

```
lpp = & ( (*lpp)->next );
```

and you can recognize `(*lpp)->next` as the next node pointer on the list.

`lpp` is a pointer to pointer. `*lpp->next` is expression known to the compiler but not the `lpp->next`.

I guess that you misunderstood
`lpp = & ( (*lpp)->next );`

as

```
lpp = &* (lpp->next);
```

and thought that `&*` would cancel itself out.

If you want to delete the node in the middle of the list you have to connect
 the node which exists before the node to be deleted to the node located after the node marked for deletion.

Something similar to:

```
         prev = current;                       
         to_free = current->next;         // node to be freed  

         prev->next = to_free->next;      // connect nodes before deletion        
         free(to_free)
```

> can you please show to me how do I delete a linked list node using
>   double poniters? – Fela93

I have added the test program for node deletion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Basic simple single list implementation to illustrate 
// a proper deletion of the node which has a specfic data value.

// Node in List
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next; // pointer to next node
}node;

// returns newly created node
node* node_new(int data)
{
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory for the node 

    if (new_node == NULL)
        return NULL;                             // protection 

    new_node->data = data;                       // remember the data 
    new_node->next = NULL;                       // no next node

    return new_node;                             // return new created node
}

// The method creates a node and prepends it at the beginning of the list.
// 
// Frequently used names for this method:
// 
// insert at head
// add first
// prepend
//
// returns new head or NULL on failer

node* add_node(node **head, node* new_node)

{
   // Add item to the front of the in_list, return pointer to the prepended node (head)    

    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(new_node == NULL)                         // problem, not enough memory
       return NULL;                              // in_list->head has not changed 

/* 
                 new_node      
                   |*| -->  NULL   
                   next        
*/       
    if(*head == NULL)                    // if list is empty 
    {
        *head = new_node;                // the new_node becomes a head   
    }
    else // list already have a head node
    {
/*
                |2|-->|1|-->NULL
                 ^ 
                 |
                 *
                head (2) (list pointer)
*/
        new_node->next = *head;         // now, the new node next pointer points to the node pointed by the list head, see below:       
/* 
          new_node     
            |3|-->     |2|-->|1|-->NULL
                        ^  
                        |
                        *
                       head (list pointer)
*/          
        *head = new_node;               // the list head has to move to new_node ( a new prepanded node)  
 /* 
          new_node       
            |3|-->  |2|-->|1|-->NULL
             ^       
             |           
             *           
            head (3) (list pointer)
*/         
    }
    return *head;                       // we are returning pinter to new_node
}

// Print out list
void print_nodes(node** head)
{
    node* node;

    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (*head == NULL){
        printf("List is empty!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("List: ");
    node = *head;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", node->data);

        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

struct node *find(struct node *start, int data)             // find p to be removed
{
    node* node;

    if (start == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node = start;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->data == data)
            return node; 

        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int delete(struct node **start, int data)
{
     struct node *p, *prev, *next, *to_free;

     if (start == NULL)                      // protection
        return 0;

     p = find(*start, data);                 // find element to be removed

     if (p == NULL)
        return 0;

     if (*start == NULL)
        return 0;                            // protection

     if(*start == p)                         // head == p
     {
        if((*start)->next !=NULL)
        {
            *start = (*start)->next;         // move head

            printf("Will be removed: %p\n",p);        
            free(p);                         // remove old head

            return 1;
        }
        else // the only node
        {
            free(p);                        // free the node pointed by *start (header)

            printf("Last node removed\n");
            *start = NULL;                  // header points to NULL 

            return 1;
        }
     }

     // p != start:

     next = *start; 
     while (next != NULL)
     {
        prev = next;                       
        to_free = next->next;                // candidate to be freed   

       if( to_free == p )
        {
            prev->next = to_free->next;      // connect nodes before deletion 

            free(to_free);                   // now free the remembered `next`
            to_free = NULL;                  // so it does not point to the released memory
            return 1;
        }

        next = next->next;                   // this node was not a match 
     } //while

    return 0; 
}

int main() {   
   node *head = NULL; 

   printf("head: %p\n", head);

   node *n1 = node_new(1);
   node *n2 = node_new(2);
   node *n3 = node_new(3);

   print_nodes(&head);

   add_node(&head, n1);
   add_node(&head, n2);
   add_node(&head, n3);

   printf("head points to:  %p\n", head);

  // list has 3 elements
   print_nodes(&head);

   delete(&head, 3);  
   print_nodes(&head);

   delete(&head, 1);  
   print_nodes(&head);

   delete(&head, 2);
   print_nodes(&head);

   printf("head points to: %p\n", head);

   print_nodes(&head);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
head: (nil)
List is empty!
head points to:  0x5617cd3802b0
List:  3 2 1
Will be removed: 0x5617cd3802b0
List:  2 1
List:  2
Last node removed
List is empty!
head points to: (nil)
List is empty!
```

Comment: *It only works if `*lpp` is the list head and there is another element on the list.* nope, it works even for the other elements.

Comment: @MatteoItalia If we are in the middle of the list `prev_el`  would not be connected to `next_el`. What do I miss? `*lpp = (*lpp)->next; ` seems to be not enough.  (prev_el)->(delete_el-)>(next_el)

Comment: Very inelegant code; all the `if (... check whether head...)` are superfluously and can be omitted by using pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @ensc Thank you for your comment. In my opinion protecting the functions from dereferencing  the `NULL` pointer is worth the trouble.

Comment: @sg7 I am not speaking about the `NULL` sanity checks but about things like `if(*start == p)` or `if(*head == NULL)                    // if list is empty`.

Comment: Resource management should be done outside of `list_delete()`.  Just unlink the node  and let `free()` it outside.  `list_delete(struct node **)` should not search for the data either.  Search for it outside.

Comment: @ensc Thank you for clarification. `if(*start == p)` is a special case. We are removing the head.   `if(*head == NULL) // if list is empty` is a protection.

Comment: The sense of using pointer-to-pointers is to avoid such checks.  Code works perfectly without them; you can implement a `list_delete()` operation with one line (or two, when you really want a sanity check whether node is `NULL`)

Comment: @ensc `delete(struct node **)` should not search for the data either. I have `*find(struct node *start, int data)` function for that. And I agree. It is nicer to supply just the  `head `and `node for removal` to `list_delete` Than you for pointing that.

Comment: @ensc  I am always open to learn and to improve the style of my code. It  sure sounds like I and the others could learn from you. Could you post your version of the code? I would gladly UPVote it.

Comment: @sg75 done; see second part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975850/2252087